# Can we model the relationship between (heap size vs latency) and (heap size vs throughput) using universal law of scalability?

Tags: theory

I have a data set of the form (heap size vs latency) and (heap size vs throughout).

As I have read in several articles, universal law of scalability models throughput against concurrency (or number of nodes). Can I use the universal scalability law equation to find  the relationship between (heap size vs latency) and (heap size vs throughput)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't.

Universal Scalability Law (USL) has two variations; [USL for hardware](https://wso2.com/blog/research/scalability-modeling-using-universal-scalability-law) and [USL for software](https://wso2.com/blog/research/measuring-software-scalability-using-universal-scalability-law)

In the USL for hardware, you get the relationship between the number of nodes and throughput (keep the concurrency per node constant).

In the USL for software, you get the relationship between the level of concurrency and throughput (keep the node count constant)

Also, using Little's Law, you can derive the relationships for average latency as well.